# How to create lists with inline functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a pythonic concept in mind:

**.py**

```
["abc" + str(i) for i in range(3)]
>>>["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"]
```

How could I do something like this in javascript?
I already tried the following:

**.js**

```
["abc" + i for (const i of Array(3).keys())]
```

But it didn't work...

**How can I write the above python line in js?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map property of the array prototype, but you have to take into account that in order for the map to iterate over array elements they already need to have some value in them, ex `abc`

```js
const result = new Array(3).fill("abc").map((val, i) => val+(i+1))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `split` and `map` for a one liner as :

```js
console.log('abc'.split('').map((el,idx,arr)=>arr.join('')+(idx+1)));
```